# Jenkins Console Output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How I remove from Jenkins Console Output these comments?

> Email was triggered for: Always
>   Sending email for trigger: Always

[image]
[image]

Comment: I assume this is added by the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), isn't it?

Comment: Yes exactly I have used Emai-ext plugin. I need to send email for Nightly Build report, and I have copy the output console in email.